# I try to make a minesweeper for practice but I got the error that I don't understand why

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StartGame
{  
   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel panel;
   private JButton[][] button = new JButton[9][9];
   private int[][] status = new int[9][9];

   public StartGame()
   {
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("MineSweeper");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(500, 500);

      panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
      for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < button.length; j++)
         {
            button[i][j] = new JButton("");
            panel.add(button[i][j]);
            status[i][j] = 0;
            button[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
         }
      }

      setMine();

      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void setMine()
   {
      Random randomNumber = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         int x = randomNumber.nextInt(9);
         int y = randomNumber.nextInt(9);
         if (status[x][y] != 1)
         {
            status[x][y] = 1;
         }
         else 
         {
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         for (int x = 0; x < button.length; x++)
         {
            for (int y = 0; y < button.length; y++)
            {
               if (e.getSource() == button[x][y])
               {
                  if (status[x][y] == 0)
                  {
                     ButtonChange(x, y);
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"YOU LOSS");
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }    
   }

   public void ButtonChange(int x, int y)
   {
      if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < button.length && y < button.length)
      {
         int num = 0;
         if (status[x][y] == 0)
         {
            num += CheckMine(x-1, y-1);
            num += CheckMine(x, y-1);
            num += CheckMine(x+1, y-1);
            num += CheckMine(x-1, y);
            num += CheckMine(x+1, y);
            num += CheckMine(x-1, y+1);
            num += CheckMine(x, y+1);
            num += CheckMine(x+1, y+1);
         }

         if (num == 0)
         {
            button[x][y].setEnabled(false);
            ButtonChange(x, y-1);
            ButtonChange(x, y+1); 
            ButtonChange(x-1, y);
            ButtonChange(x+1, y);
         }
         else 
         {
            button[x][y].setEnabled(false);
            button[x][y].setText(Integer.toString(num));
         }
      }
   }

   public int CheckMine(int x, int y)
   {  
      int num = 0;
      if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < button.length && y < button.length)
      {
         if (status[x][y] == 1)
         {
            num = 1;
         }
      }
      return num;
   }
}
```

This is my code, I haven't finish yet cause I haven't make the method to check winning. 
Main program is in another class. 
I got an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at javax.swing.JComponent.disable(JComponent.java:3638) 
at java.awt.Component.enable(Component.java:1517) 
at java.awt.Component.setEnabled(Component.java:1480) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.setEnabled(JComponent.java:2680) 
at    javax.swing.AbstractButton.setEnabled(AbstractButton.java:2091) 
at StartGame.ButtonChange(StartGame.java:104)
at StartGame.ButtonChange(StartGame.java:103)
```

when I try to click some button. 
I don't understand why because I check it and it seems to be correct. 
It didn't work out in the ButtonChange function only for the upper and lower button change but not the left and right. I just don't get what happen in my program.....

Comment: That's not an error message. Post full error message please.

Comment: Please show us the error message (i.e. the lines above `at StartGame.Button...)

Comment: sorry about that
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at javax.swing.JComponent.disable(JComponent.java:3638)
 at java.awt.Component.enable(Component.java:1517)
 at java.awt.Component.setEnabled(Component.java:1480)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.setEnabled(JComponent.java:2680)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setEnabled(AbstractButton.java:2091)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The problem is that you have a matrix of buttons and you are trying to setEnabled(false) the whole matrix... you have to setEnable each button explicit...</strike>

try to disabled with two for loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
  for(int j = 0 ; j<9; j++){
    button[i][j].setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

That's not the problem... The problem is caused because you are doing a bad use of recursivity... the method ButtonChange is called by itself too deep... Let's say that the arguments of the first call is (2,2)... The method will call itself with (2,1) then with (2,0), then (2,-1) then with (2,3) and that start again with (2,2) then (2,1)... so that makes that appear that stackOverFlow Error

If you put a System.out.println("X= "+x+" and Y= "+y); in the first line of the method and try again you will see the problem...

**UPDATE:**

The problem is in your method ButtonChange(int x, int y) because in there you call recursively the method with parameters that create a infinite call... let me show you an example in order to make me understand

One example of recursivity is the fibonacci's series... I can create the next code to find out a value of that serie in some point:

```
 public int fibonacci(int value){
     if(value == 1 || value == 2){
         return 1;
     }else{
         return fibonacci(value-1)+fibonacci(value-2);
     }
 }
```

If I want to know the value of the serie with value = 4:

[image: fibonacci(4)=3]

But check the next code:

```
public int fibonacci(int value){
    if(value == 1 || value == 2 || value > 8){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return fibonacci(value-1)+fibonacci(value+1);
    }
}
```

Check that into the method I call the method recursively with "value-1" and "value+1"

Now if I want to know the value of the serie with value = 4:

[image: f(4)=Error]

In this point if you look carefully we have that f(3) = f(2) + **f(4)** AND f(5) = **f(4)** + f(6) and if you remember **f(4)** was the inital value of the function, so that means that now the original function appear inside the iterations. That makes not only that the recursion is bigger in every call of the method but that never the iterations will end... so finally that will generate a java.lang.StackOverFlow Error

That's a similar behavior that you have in your function ButtonChange when you inside the function do

ButtonChange(x, y-1);
ButtonChange(x, y+1);
 
ButtonChange(x-1, y);
ButtonChange(x+1, y);

Comment: I don't quite understand because the x and y in button[x][y] is the value that given by
public void ButtonChange(int x, int y)
so I am thinking that it should one specific button only

Comment: You're right, I didn't look that, that's not the problem...

The problem is caused because you are doing a bad use of recursivity... the method ButtonChange is called by itself too deep...

Let's say that the arguments of the first call is (2,2)...

The method will call itself with (2,1) then with (2,0), then (2,-1) then with (2,3) and that start again with (2,2) then (2,1)... so that makes that appear that stackOverFlow Error... If you make a debug at your code you will see that ;)

Comment: but it is how it suppose to work isn't it? If what you click is zero mine near you, then the system should click the one around that button. Afterall, it will appear like a big area by one click, then you can guess where the mine is

Comment: But you have to verify the recursivity in that code... try with the system.out and check... you are doing a bad recursion, you have to verify that part of the code

Comment: I find out what's wrong in my program, when the button have a recursion, it will check the last button again so it checks up and down and up and down. Therefore, I make a method to check before the buttonchange
   public boolean CheckButton(int x, int y)
   {
      boolean isWorked = true;
      if (!(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < button.length && y < button.length))
      {
         isWorked = false;
      }
      if (isWorked)
      {
         if (button[x][y].isEnabled())
         {
            isWorked = false;
         }
      }
However, it still doesn't work. Can you try to figure why?

Comment: The problem is in your method ButtonChange(int x, int y) because in there you call recursively the method with parameters that create a infinite call...

I will update my answer to put and example and make me understand

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're jumping right and left indefinitely with recursion. it would be enough to add information about the state of the cell (discovered/not discovered):

```
private Boolean[][] checked = new Boolean[9][9];
```

or use the button status. Then modify the main condition in:

```
if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < button.length && y < button.length && !checked[x][y])
```

or

```
if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < button.length && y < button.length && !button[x][y].isEnabled())
```

then it should work.